# How does the third parameter in open() system call work?

Tags: c, unix

```
int fd = open("float.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
```

I know the 0600 has to do with permissions, but how exactly does it work?

Comment: You literally re-wrote your question to ask something entirely different after I gave you the answer to your original issue. Next time, just accept the answer (if it solves your issue), then ask a separate question for follow-up.

Comment: Everything you need to know about unix file permission values is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html). The `0600` value is the octal union of `0400` (owner has read permission) with `0200` (owner has write permission).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the 3 param version of `open` when using the O_CREAT flag:

As per [the man page for open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
>
> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
>
> The mode argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when
>                 a new file is created.  This argument must be supplied when
>                 O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is specified in flags; if neither O_CREAT
>                 nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then mode is ignored.

Try this instead:

```
int fd = open("float.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
```